# How to render an action plus GET parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 4 application I have this controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  SECTIONS = %w(time currency letterhead)

  def edit
    section = Profile::SECTIONS.include?(params[:section]) ? params[:section] : Profile::SECTIONS[0]
    session[:section] = section
  end

  def update
    if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to edit_profile_path(:section => session[:section])
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

end
```

In the view, each user's profile record is spread across three different tabs using GET parameters.

E.g. when the user is in the "time" tab and successfully saves it, s/he is redirected to that same tab. Nice!

But unfortunately, when the save is unsuccessful (and Rails' validation kicks in), that doesn't work.

I tried adding a parameter to `render` but to no avail.

Can anybody tell me what's the best way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you showing tabs on View? JavaScript? Could you post the relevant view and JS(if it's done in JS as well) code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're checking `params[:section]` in the view and you're using its value to determine which tab to show.  So the easiest solution is to just set `params[:section]` in the else part.

```
if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
  redirect_to edit_profile_path(:section => session[:section])
else
  params[:section] = session[:section]
  render :edit
end
```

Another easier way is to just use `session[:section]` in the view so you don't have to pass it in between requests.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works! Can you also tell me how exactly I might use `session[:section]` in the view?

Comment: same way as you're using `params`.  if you have something like `if params[:section] == 'something'`, then just change that to `if session[:section] == 'something'`

Answer (score 1):

```
render :edit, :locals => {:params1 => "value"}
```

Use `locals` to pass paramters in render